# Как исправить регулярное выражение, чтобы оно работало?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярное выражение.
Cтрока должна содержать:

- хотя бы одно число
- хотя бы две буквы латинского алфавита в разных регистрах
- хотя бы один символ из ряда `! ? . , + - * / =`
- содержит не менее `10` символов

Вот мои потуги

```
/[a-z]{1,}[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[!\?\.,\+\*/=]{1,0}{10,}/
```

Однако, выдает кучу ошибок. Очевидно, я не понимаю как сделать условие "хотя бы". Как дописать `regexp` чтобы оно получилось верное?

**UPDATE**

Для меня сработало это:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!?.,+*\/=-]).{10,}$/
```

Comment: На enSO есть похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150/regex-for-password-must-contain-at-least-eight-characters-at-least-one-number-a)

Comment: между пунктами должно стоять И или ИЛИ то есть 1Az!1Az!1Az! является валидной или !aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa также валидна

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nHOM5q/1 - отличный тренажер что бы составить выражение

Comment: @ganz выражение в примере не будет работать, `{1,0}{10,}` - нельзя просто так взять и квантифицировать квантификатор, и диапазон `{1,0}` задается не так это либо `{0,1}` либо `?`

Comment: @ipatev_nn, я знаю, поэтому и не скинул свой код D ... но вероятно ты писал не мне ...

Comment: @ganz, да, не правильно понял, вы условия уточняете, а я подумал что комментируете уже написанный регэксп)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-!?.,+*\/=]).{10,}$/
```

Comment: @Leonid, исправил.

Comment: @Qwertiy Всёравно [ошибка](https://regex101.com/r/LmtAa6/1)

Comment: /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!?.,+*\/=-]).{10,}$/

Comment: @Leonid, дефис надо в начало или конец ставить. Во многих языках ещё можно в места, где символы не идут по возрастанию, но в js, похоже, не работает. Он же обозначает диапазон. Я Поторопился и просто скопипастил как было.

Comment: @nazarpunk, дефис переставить надо было...

Comment: Прошу прощения за самодеятельность(( Хотелось плюс поставить очень))

Comment: @Leonid, да я не против :) Просто мне больше нравится в начале, вот и поправил ещё раз. Я просто тогда торопился и накосячил)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагая явно расписать каждое условие для наглядности.

```js
const {log,dir} = console;

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    checkString(e.target.value);
})



String.prototype.howmuch = function(pattern){
    return [...this.matchAll(pattern)].length;
}

function checkString(string){
    if(string.howmuch(/\d/g) >= 1 &&
    string.howmuch(/[a-z]/g) >= 1 &&
    string.howmuch(/[A-Z]/g) >= 1 &&
    string.howmuch(/[!|?|.|,|+|\-|*|/|=]/g) >=1 &&
    string.length >= 10
    ){
        log('Yes it has all');
    } else {
        log('Something has missed');
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Это, конечно, буквально 10 символов, включая пробелы. Но все согласно условиям. Можно поменять на количество непробельных символов, например.